# Python Payroll Caculator

Tags: python, calculator

My assignment is to create a payroll calculator that asks the user for number of hours worked in a week and asks for the hourly pay rate. Hours worked up to and including 40 hours per week are paid at the given payrate. Hours worked above 40 but less than or equal to 60 get paid at 1.5 times their regular hourly rate. Hours worked above 60 hours will get paid 2 times their regular hourly rate.

I can seem to figure out how to get the program to calculate the pay including the 2 times rate above 60 hrs. It calculates at only 1.5 times the hourly rate.

THANK YOU!

```
base_hours = 40
xtra_hours = 60
over_time = 1.5
xover_time = 2.0

hours = float(input('Enter the amount of hours worked: '))
pay_rate = float(input('Enter the hourly pay rate: ')

if hours > base_hours:
overtime_hours = hours - base_hours
overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * over_time
gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate + overtime_pay

elif hours > 60:
overtime_hours = hours - base_hours 
overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * xover_time
gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate * overtime_pay

else:
gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

print('The gross pay is $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'), sep='')
```

Comment: You misunderstood the comparison logic. When it says _up to 40_ it means `<= 40` . Same goes for the `elif` which is `<= 60`.

Answer (score 0):

your first if conditional needs to be more specific:

```
if hours > base_hours and hours < 60:
```

Otherwise, as long as hours are above base hours, then the first conditional will be met at 1.5 times the rate
Full code below:

```
base_hours = 40
xtra_hours = 60
over_time = 1.5
xover_time = 2.0

hours = float(input('Enter the amount of hours worked: '))
pay_rate = float(input('Enter the hourly pay rate: '))

if (hours > base_hours) and (hours < 60):
    overtime_hours = hours - base_hours
    overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * over_time
    gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate + overtime_pay

elif hours > 60:
    overtime_hours = hours - base_hours 
    overtime_pay = overtime_hours * pay_rate * xover_time
    gross_pay = base_hours * pay_rate * overtime_pay

else:
    gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

print 'The gross pay is', gross_pay
```

Comment: Thank you, adding and hours <  60: gives me a syntax error on the greater than sign.

Comment: ok it might be because you were missing a parenthesis... can you try the full code above?

Comment: Tried that code, my original code was calculation $50 below what it was suppose to and with the revisions it is now calculating $300 over. I'm going to play around with it a little more and see where I can get.